# HP Proliant ML110 G6 using centOS - Hardware RAID fault alert

Tags: centos, raid, hp, hp-proliant

We have installed centOS 5 on an HP Proliant ML110 G6 server and we've setup RAID1+0 on it through the BIOS.

My question would be: is it possible to send an e-mail of the status of the RAID controller every now and then? Or at least, when the status of the RAID controller is changed, i.e. when it becomes faulty?

Anyone has any idea how to do it?

I've been searching a lot but didn't find something conclusive.

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What raid controllers? Most of the entry level RAID controllers in HP servers are what is known as "FakeRaid". Software RAID with drivers making it look like hardware RAID. SmartRAID B110i is a classic example of this and is generally unsupported by Linux without HP driver disks (I'd still recommend strongly against using it, linux software raid is better in this case).
Can you confirm what RAID controller it is?

Answer (score 0):

On my server i have set op a task(windows) when the raid controller daemon/driver is writhing an error or critical event it sends me a email.

I think linux can do something similar

HP raid agent, http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/servers/proliantstorage/software-management/acumatrix/index.html

Comment: I installed the utility and it's saying 'No Controllers found' :/

Comment: Maybe this can help
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-hardware-18/raid-array-not-detected-new-hp-ml150g6-server-739130/